# Boot error Parrot OS after configuring Nvidia Graphics

Tags: ubuntu, boot, debian, multiple-monitors, parrot-os

I tried to install a second monitor by following the steps here:

https://community.parrotsec.org/t/external-monitor-with-nvidia-drivers-on-laptop-extended-display-working/24820

But after finishing and rebooting, I get this error and my OS is not booting up:

[image]

Specs: Parrot os 5.0.1

The OS is installed as main system and is not a bootable usb.

Does anybody know a way other than formating :(

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot in UEFI? Likely not so do it and try again.

Comment: @ChangAuto secure boot is already disabled ;(